# How and Where To Implement a Cross-Platform App Config File?

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform

I need to implement a cross-platform app configuration file for the PCL project to add a parameter. Where would it exist in the solution structure? Do I need to add any packages, like 'PCLAppConfig", to use it? I currently have it with the tradition naming pattern, i.e. project.exe.config, in the PCL project, but it isn't recognizing the element, failing on builds.

[image]

[image]

Comment: iOS and Android projects don't have any concept of the standard .NET config file.  You can mimic this behavior by using a package like PCLAppConfig

Comment: Thanks Jason. Moved to the newest version of Xamarin.